# Using JavaScript variables for django template list lookup

Tags: jquery, django

I've used js vars before with django templates, and it has worked, but this case is a bit different.

I need to use js var as a list index number to look up objects from a passed list in a django template var.

```
var index = 0;
$(.someclass).html (
    {{ list.index.some_attr }}
}
```

This does not work, and what's weird is I tested this:

```
$(.someclass).html (
     {{ list.0.some_attr }}
 )
```

And it works!, This also works:

```
var index = 0;
$(.someclass).html (
     index
}
```

This is a bit confusing, can anyone give an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Django's template language doesnt support bracket indexing

Answer (score 0):

You cant access an iterable's member attribute without iterating it or pointing the member by index. This is quite normal in OOP. That said what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Did you read my code? I am using an index to point to that object. The problem which I am trying to solve is the fact that it's not working. list.0.attr works, but var = 0; list.var.attr does not work

Comment: You cant call by key on lists you are confused youll need to pass a DICT

Comment: Oh I see well JavaScript is evaluated after the rendered template so thats not going to work

Comment: list.0.attr and list.1.attr, so on works. It's just that this js var won't register properly.

Comment: Errr no? Django already parses the resulting object to the template, your list does not have keys so list.var fails. JS cant access that process, gladly. Also I cant think of any use case where you would want to. Maybe you want Ajax?

Comment: Im iterating a list and pointing at objects whose index corresponds to a js var, are u sure nobody ever does this...

Comment: You can assign {{ list|json }} to a js var but youll have create the filter or return json from the view.